# Error: Package doesn't exists when importing a user defined package

Tags: java, package

I am trying to import a package, but when compiling it shows error like :

```
Package doesn't exists
```

I tried the same with a small example, but again the same error is raising.
here is the sample code :

```
D : company
        |-salary
```

Above is the directory structure.

```
package company.salary;

public class Income
{
private int value;

public int getValue() { return this.value; }
}
```

---

```
package company;

import company.salary.*;


public class Budget
{

  public int calculateSavings()
{


    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: how do you compile this?

Answer (score 1):

To compile, go to the root and use paths:

```
D:\>javac company\Budget.java
```

The compiler has a slightly peculiar way of looking for source code files, [documented here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html). Alternatively you could add the root to the class path explicitly:

```
javac -classpath D:\ Budget.java
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `import company.salary.*`

As it is already inside in Company package.So it is never used.

So your structure should be like this:
In Company package there will be another Salary package and Budget.java and in Salary package it will be income.java file.

Budget.Java

```
package company;

public class Budget
{

  public int calculateSavings()
  {


    return 0;
  }
}
```

Income.java

```
package company.salary;

public class Income
{
       private int value;


       public int getValue()
       { 
                 return this.value;
       }
}
```

If you don't already know this, you should probably read this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html#Understanding

Comment: here is the actual import structure..                                           package com.ducont.notis.database;
import com.ducont.notis.utils.*;
import com.ducont.notis.utils.MessageResource;
import com.ducont.notis.utils.PC1Decrypt;
import com.ducont.notis.utils.Utils;

Comment: In which package you are getting error..?And give your full code so that we can know error..Here i gave solution as per your Salary and Company package example.

Comment: I again observed your updated code.I also tried this same in ecllipse. But i didn't get any error

Answer (score 1):

No need to `import company.salary.*` it is already inside the company package. Why you don't use eclipse or NetBeans IDE, it will make your task easier, simply write code and let the IDE to make suggestions for your errors.